# Converting integers into bytes

Tags: java

How do the following numbers, on byte conversion give the results on right hand side ? I guess when you convert an integer to a byte array, it should convert each of the digit of that number into its correponding 4 byte array. But here's what  cannot understand..

`727 = 000002D7`

`1944 = 00000798`

`42 = 0000002A`

**EDIT:** I was reading a blog where I found these following lines:-

*If we are working with integer column names, for example, then each column name is 4 bytes long. Lets work with column names 727, 1944 and 42.*

*The bytes associated with these three numbers:*

`727 = 000002D7`

`1944 = 00000798`

`42 = 0000002A`

link to this blog: http://www.divconq.com/2010/why-does-cassandra-have-data-types/

Comment: Looks okay... the printed value is the hex equivalent.

Comment: is it converted to hex & then the hex is stored as byte array?? but why??

Comment: why not just simply convert each digit to corresponding bytes ?

Comment: Apparently someone printed it in hex.

Comment: so normally, during byte conversion the integers are not converted, at any step, into hexadecimals right ? This has been done by someone explicitly.. !?

Comment: That representation on the right is HEX notation. Not strictly bytes.

Comment: The blog sounds confused.  Why are columns _named_ with numbers, and if that's the case what does converting the names to hex have to do with anything?  Edit your post and add a link to the blog.

Comment: Again, this is nothing particularly to do with "bytes". It's the hexadecimal representation (see e.g. `Integer.toHexString(i)`).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The following will give you the exact output as in your example:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        System.out.format("%08X\n", 727);
        System.out.format("%08X\n", 1944);
        System.out.format("%08X\n", 42);
    }
}
```

and here is the expected output:

```
000002D7
00000798
0000002A
```

**Explanation**

How the [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) works, the format from right to left string says, `x` = format as hexadecimal, `08` = pad to the left eight characters with `0` and the `%` marks the beginning of the pattern.

You can also use `String.format("%08X", 727);` to accomplish the same thing.